# Signal/Slot problem with PySide6 (but not with PyQt6)

Tags: python, pyside6, pyqt6, qt6

Consider the following code where clicking a button is closing the parent window.
Using PyQt6, the parent window of the button clicked is closed.
But with PySide6, the window 1 is always closed, whatever the button clicked.
I cannot figure out what is happening. Is there something wrong in my code, or is it a PySide6 bug?

**PyQt6 code:**

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    closed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton(name)
        button.clicked.connect(self.closed.emit)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication([])
win1 = MyWindow("win1")
win1.closed.connect(win1.close)
win1.show()
win2 = MyWindow("win2")
win2.closed.connect(win2.close)
win2.show()
app.exec()
```

**PySide6 code:**

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    closed = Signal()

    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton(name)
        button.clicked.connect(self.closed.emit)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication([])
win1 = MyWindow("win1")
win1.closed.connect(win1.close)
win1.show()
win2 = MyWindow("win2")
win2.closed.connect(win2.close)
win2.show()
app.exec()
```

Versions used:

- Pyside 6.5.1
- PyQt 6.5.0
- Python 3.11.3
- OS : Linux

Comment: nice catch! this does seem to be weird/unexpected behavior, so bug, I guess ? Micght be worth reporting.

Comment: It seems to be this bug, specific to PySide 6.5.1 : [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-2346)

Comment: Fixed in PySide 6.5.1.1