# Pyside 6.5.1 widget created in for-loop has wrong attributes

Tags: python, for-loop, pyside6, qpushbutton

I am using pyside6 in the current version 6.5.1.
I encounter the following problem which I did not have in version 6.4.2. The buttons displayed in the main window are assigned object names, which are to be printed by clicking. However, all buttons always print "row=0, col=0" after click.
The same happens with other widget attributes.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QWidget, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QApplication


class CustomButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget, row: int, col: int, slot: Callable):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setObjectName(f'{row=}, {col=}')
        self.setText(f'{row=}, {col=}')
        self.released.connect(lambda: slot(self))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent: QApplication):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.create_buttons()

    def create_buttons(self):
        for r in range(10):
            for c in range(10):
                button = CustomButton(self, r, c, self.button_clicked)
                self.layout.addWidget(button, r, c)

    def button_clicked(self, button: QPushButton):
        print(button.objectName())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow(app)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

With version 6.4.2, however, the correct object names are printed.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I can confirm the different behaviour between 6.4.2 and 6.5.1. But the buttons do have the correct attributes. If you add a method to the CustomButton class that prints `self.objectName()` and you connect the clicked (or released) signal to that, it will print the correct values. If you use a lambda it will print zeroes again.

Comment: Probably related to [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-2346) (see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76373822/signal-slot-problem-with-pyside6-but-not-with-pyqt6)

Comment: Thank you @mahkitah! That's correct. But tht means that the button widget does not return the rel object. That's strange! Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Thank you @musicamante. That seams to be a bug in versin 6.5.1. With version 6.5.0 everything runs correctly.

Comment: @ThomasRuff No, it means that the called function is wrong, as *all* signals connected to the same function reference will always trigger just the *first* connected function, even if they belong to a different widget: if you click on the last button, the *first* function will be called.

Comment: @musicamante you are right. Thanks! I will use version 6.5.0 in my project hoping this issue will soon be handled.

Comment: @ThomasRuff It already has been: the report shows 6.5.1.1 as a fix version, meaning that it will be available at least since 6.5.2 if you cannot use local builds or your package manager doesn't provide minor build versions.